# отображение дополнительной информации в развёрнутом asp dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webforms

Есть массив `{'a1', 'b1'; 'a2', 'b2'; 'a3', 'b3'}`

Есть dropdownlist, в котором отображаются `{'a1', 'a2', 'a3'}`

Хотелось бы, чтобы в свёрнутом виде отображалось `'a1'`, а в развёрнутом отображались строки формата `a1 (b1)`.

Подскажите варианты решения. Пока только в голову приходит написать свой контрол унаследованный от dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На клиентской стороне можно попробовать использовать JQuery UI ComboBox. В [примере](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) из документации показано как использовать настройку отображения:

```
//...
.autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
//...
```

Comment: Сейчас используется asp dropdownlist с привязкой источника данных типа datatable. Хотелось бы иметь решение в рамках ASP.NET.

Comment: @AydarGarafutdinov Решание в рамках ASP.NET все равно будет рендериться в js и html *) Вы предложили написать контрол, так вот его рендерить на клиенте можно через jquery ui...